# How do I change the input text box size in Jupyter debugger?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I drop into debugger in my jupyter notebooks using:

```
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
set_trace()
```

But the text boxes (the ones following the `ipdb>` prompt) for entering commands are really short. How can I make them bigger by default? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use i.e. Chrome's Developer Tools and navigate through the HTML elements until you track down how the CSS class of the debug text field is called.

[image: preview of developer tools]

Once you found the class name, you can inject CSS into a notebook from another cell like this:

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML("""
<style>
.jp-Stdin-input {
    width: 80% !important;
}
</style>
""")
```

The result is then a gigantic debug text field.

[image: big debug field]

If you want this to become permanent, you need to change your `custom.css` file.

I did not try this, but depending on your installation it may be one of this files:

- `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.css`
- `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`

Answer (score 1):

Click the left side to expand the text box.

[image]